# jQuery menu : animate background to item hover

Tags: jquery, menu

I want to animate background of active menu item between other items when mouse hover on them, like the flash file in this link:

http://www.w-enter.com/forum/f63/t35513/#.UHqbam_MiRo

Comment: You do? Where are you stuck? How far have you got? What HTML are you using?

Comment: I think you want something like this : http://apycom.com/

Comment: that like Mona Abdelmajeed post, and I want the way to do that by any HTML code then I'll edit it.